# How to cover following with tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, code-coverage

after installing NCrunch I have found out that a lot of lines are not covered by tests. For example following code.

```
using System;

namespace Ei.Exceptions
{
  public class FactoryException: Exception
  {
    public object Factory { get; private set; }

    public FactoryException(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }

    public FactoryException(object factory, string message) : base(message) {
        this.Factory = factory;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to write a test, but it does not cover it:

```
[TestFixture]
class FactoryExceptionTest
{
    [Test]
    void FactoryException_Created_ReturnsInstance()
    {
        var exception = new FactoryException("Test");
        Assert.AreEqual(exception.Message, "Test");

        var exception2 = new FactoryException("Factory", "Test");
        Assert.AreEqual(exception.Message, "Test");
        Assert.AreEqual(exception.Factory, "Factory");
    }
}
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: That looks like it should be covered to me. Are you sure you are not referencing the dll containing the FactoryException instead of the project?

Comment: [`Missing Code Coverage`](https://www.ncrunch.net/documentation/troubleshooting_missing-code-coverage). Maybe that what has happened...

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the default access modifier for a class in C# is `internal`. Since you did not specify `public` for your test class, I'm guessing NCrunch does not see it from the tested assembly.

Comment: I agree, I suspect your test runner is not running this test - check the test report.